# How can i access php complex array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [success] => 1
            [result] => Array
                (
                    [success] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1958856
                                    [device_id] => 7565
                                    [message] => ....
                                    [status] => pending
                                    [send_at] => 1416564932
                                    [queued_at] => 0
                                    [sent_at] => 0
                                    [delivered_at] => 0
                                    [expires_at] => 1416568532
                                    [canceled_at] => 0
                                    [failed_at] => 0
                                    [received_at] => 0
                                    [error] => 
                                    [created_at] => 1416564932
                                    [contact] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 312505
                                            [name] => 123
                                            [number] => 123
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [fails] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => 200
```

i need to get [id] => 1958856.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please try and format your code effectively so people can easily read it.

Comment: Just follow the dump "tree". Every indent level is another key/object reference to add to your code.

Comment: Checkout the [excellent PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). I have even linked to the page that would tell you the ins and outs of arrays in PHP.

Comment: I tried a lot of things, haha but my fail was here `$array['response']['result']['success']['0']['id'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array['response']['result']['success'][0]['id'];
```

this should get to it

*Additional details from **iWontStop**:*

**How it works**

This is called a multi-dimensional array. They're found in many languages (most useful ones I'd say).

To access an item within the Array, for php it uses `[]`. You can then place a string, number or variable containing one of the two within the `[]` like so:

`$variable['key'];`

If an item within an Array is also an Array you simply repeat the process of the `[]` like so:

`$variable['key']['keytwo'];`

Comment: Thankyou, is verry simple, i try evrething and was so easy. Tnx